# Is map applied on all the list before filter findAny?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, short-circuiting

I want to filter a list for elements having a non null property and returning that property:

```
list.stream.map(a -> StringUtils.trimToEmpty(a.getProp())).filter( p -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(p)).findAny().orElse("");
```

Do the code above first map all the elements? For efficiency reasons I'd like to process element by element.

Comment: No, map operation lazy and go one by one in pipeline

Comment: So it works: it will stop to the first mapping if the prop is not null?

Comment: Yes, see the details in  @Nikolas answer

Comment: This is actually one of the core principles and advantages of streaming compared to other more traditional approaches. Most of the operations are "lazy" and only build up an operation pipeline. The elements are send through the pipeline one by one as soon as you have a terminal operation and not before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Stream::findAny`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) is a [short-circuiting terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps), which in a nutshell means that if an item is present, it terminates the Stream.

Ie. if the first element is qualified for the `Stream::filter` pipe and passes it through, the `Stream::findAny` returns it immediately without processing further elements in the original collection.

There is a nice proof using `Stream::peek` to understand how Stream API works (let's say a class `Foo` has only one final String parameter `prop`):

```
List<Foo> list = List.of(
   new Foo(""),            // the first is empty and doesn't pass through Stream::filter
   new Foo("one"),         // this is qualified
   new Foo("two"));        // this is qualified

list.stream()
    .peek(item -> System.out.println("# Streamed    " + item.getProp())) // streamed
    .map(a -> StringUtils.trimToEmpty(a.getProp()))
    .peek(item -> System.out.println("#  Mapped     " + item))           // mapped
    .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
    .peek(item -> System.out.println("#   Filtered  " + item))           // filtered
    .findAny()
    .orElse("");
```

The output shows the first element doesn't pass through `Stream::filter` (is empty) and ended before `Stream::map`. The second element passed through `Stream::filter` and the subsequent `Stream::map` and reached finally `Stream::findAny`. As long as `Stream::findAny` is a short-circuiting and terminal operation with a present result, it terminates the Stream.

```
# Streamed    
#  Mapped     
# Streamed    one
#  Mapped     one
#   Filtered  one
```